# Add header only for some URIs handled by index.php

Tags: nginx

I have a general `location` block that matches `/` prefix and executes `try_files` that hits `/index.php`. `/index.php` is in turn handled by another `location` block that matches paths ending in `.php` and does `fastcgi_pass`.

What I need is to `add_header` to the response for *some* URIs handled by this chain of `location` blocks, *but not for others*. I am allowed to add extra `location` blocks *matching those special URIs*, but I am **NOT** allowed to hardcode special URIs anywhere or anyhow in those two general `location` blocks.

How can I achieve this with as little configuration duplication as possible, and also without requiring that the application supply a separate .php file as an entrypoint for handling every special URI?